# Spinor index, dirac field equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, notation, fermions, spinors, anticommutator

Sometimes I read anticommute
$$\{\psi(x),\psi^\dagger(y)\}=\delta^{(3)}(x-y)$$
Sometimes,
$$\{\psi_a(x),\psi_b^\dagger(y)\}=\delta^{(3)}(x-y)\delta_{ab}$$
Are they the same, second one just emphasis everything happens as a outer-product?

Answer (score 2):

in all generality, the spinor in Dirac equation are "vector" of size $\left \lceil{d/2}\right \rceil $ with d the space time dimension.

When one writes the anticommutation relation for such objects, one write abusively $$\{\psi(x),\psi^\dagger(y)\}=\delta^{(3)}(x-y)$$ instead of the proper $$\{\psi(x),\psi^\dagger(y)\}=\delta^{(3)}(x-y)\mathbb{1}$$ representing all the commutation at once.

Another proper way to write these relations is to write them index by index of your spinor or in other words

$$\{\psi_a(x),\psi_b^\dagger(y)\}=\delta^{(3)}(x-y)\delta_{ab}$$

insisting on the role of the index. This is in fact nothing but the (a,b) component of the matrix form identity written previously.

Comment: Follow up, that means, $(\psi_a)^T$ may be represented by the set $\{(\sqrt{p\sigma}\xi^1,\sqrt{p\overline{\sigma}}\xi^1)e^{-ipx},(\sqrt{p\sigma}\xi^2,\sqrt{p\overline{\sigma}}\xi^2)e^{-ipx},(\sqrt{p\sigma}\eta^1,-\sqrt{p\overline{\sigma}}\eta^1)e^{ipx},(\sqrt{p\sigma}\eta^2,-\sqrt{p\overline{\sigma}}\eta^2)e^{ipx}\}$ or it means $\{\sqrt{p\sigma}\xi^1e^{-ipx},\sqrt{p\sigma}\xi^2e^{-ipx},\sqrt{p\overline{\sigma}}\eta^1e^{ipx},-\sqrt{p\overline{\sigma}}\eta^2e^{-ipx}\}$, that is, is $\psi_a$ refers to the spinor or bispinor?

Comment: Huh? Ask that as a separate question please.